# What could the meaning of "invariant of $G$" be?

Tags: terminology, finite-groups

In a context, the author wrote that **for a finite permutation group $G$ acting on a set $\Omega$ of degree $n$, the list of subdegrees is an invariant of the group**.  What could the meaning of "invariant of $G$" be? Does it mean *invariant of group under the group action* or I am wrong?

Comment: What context? What is a subdegree?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Permutaion Groups by J.D.Dixon. It is a lenght of the orbit of one of the point stablizres. Thanks

Comment: I don't have this book and cannot understand what is meant here. Can you quote a longer passage?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for the time Prof.,in a Theorem 3.2B., he took somewhere a $\Sigma$ subset of $\Omega$ x $\Omega$ an $G$-invarant when for all $x\in G$, $\Sigma(\alpha)^x=\Sigma(\alpha^x)$ wherein a group $G$ acts transitively on the set $\Omega$. Is this the same he quoted above?

Comment: The lengths of the orbits of a point stabilizer are invariants of the *permutation group* $G$. So yes, it's an invariant of the group action. Different action have (generally) different subdegrees.